# Lirc not running, yet the remote can control the desktop. Through what?

Tags: remote-control, lirc

I am trying to configure my remote. The good news, is that it "Just worked". Meaning: I plugged it in, ran the gnome-lirc-properties and now I can control some parts of my desktop with it.

It seems, though, that it is not lirc handling it. I have killed lircd. It does not show under ps:

```
ps faux | grep ir
#shows a few processes, like firefox, but nothing like lirc(d), irw, irrecord etc.
```

The device is still active thought:

```
sudo cat /dev/lirc0
```

Pressing buttons on my remote make it print all sorts of strings.

Pressing buttons on my remote actually control Gnome/Unity/Desktop. E.g. Volume up and down make the volume go up and down, mute works, the "windows-button" fires up banshee and so on.

What is reading out my remote? And how can I configure that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Florian said, Ubuntu is seeing the remote as a keyboard.

You can add the below to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to stop X from picking it up:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Remote"
  MatchProduct "<your transceiver input name>"
  Options "Ignored" "True"
EndSection
```

(If there is no xorg.conf, just create it (`sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`))

To get your input name:

```
cat /proc/bus/input | grep Name
```

(Just pick the one that seems closest to what you think it is, mine is "Media Center Ed. eHome Infrared Remote Transceiver")

Then install lirc (`sudo apt-get install lirc`) and go through the setup process (I have to run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lirc` to get the setup dialog to run for some odd reason)

Then reboot (or run `sudo restart lightdm` and log back in)

Answer (score 3):

Quite likely your remote is used as a keyboard. I don't know any real useful docs for how to configure it but `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-keymap.rules` and the files in `/lib/udev/keymaps/` may give you some idea about how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct version of the Option line:

```
Option "Ignore" "True"
```